# How to query with '$in' over '_id' in reactive mongo and play

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, reactivemongo

I have a project set up with `playframework 2.2.0` and `play2-reactivemongo 0.10.0-SNAPSHOT`. I'd like to query for few documents by their ids, in a fashion similar to this:

```
def usersCollection = db.collection[JSONCollection]("users")
val ids: List[String] = /* fetched from somewhere else */
val query = ??
val users = usersCollection.find(query).cursor[User].collect[List]()
```

As a query I tried:

```
Json.obj("_id" -> Json.obj("$in" -> ids))                        // 1
Json.obj("_id.$oid" -> Json.obj("$in" -> ids))                   // 2
Json.obj("_id" -> Json.obj("$oid" -> Json.obj("$in" -> ids)))    // 3
```

for which first and second return empty lists and the third fails with error `assertion 10068 invalid operator: $oid`.

Comment: Why not `Json.obj("_id" -> Json.obj("$in" -> ids.map(BSONObjectID(_))))`?

Comment: @Dom because then you have to have instance of `Write[BSONObjectID]` in implicit scope, and `play-reactivemongo` offers only partial one. Moreover, writing one feels not efficient, as you'll do conversion `BSONValue` -> `JsValue` -> `BSONValue` in this case.

Comment: Ok, get what you mean, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

*NOTE: copy of my response on the ReactiveMongo mailing list.*

First, sorry for the delay of my answer, I may have missed your question.
Play-ReactiveMongo cannot guess on its own that the values of a Json array are ObjectIds.  That's why you have to make a Json object for each id that looks like this: `{"$oid": "526fda0f9205b10c00c82e34"}`.  When the ReactiveMongo Play plugin sees an object which first field is `$oid`, it treats it as an ObjectId so that the driver can send the right type for this value (`BSONObjectID` in this case.)

This is a more general problem actually: the JSON format does not match exactly the BSON one.  That's the case for numeric types (`BSONInteger`, `BSONLong`, `BSONDouble`), `BSONRegex`, `BSONDateTime`, and `BSONObjectID`.  You may find more detailed information in the MongoDB documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/ .

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it with:

```
val objectIds = ids.map(id => Json.obj("$oid" -> id))
val query = Json.obj("_id" -> Json.obj("$in" -> objectIds))
usersCollection.find(query).cursor[User].collect[List]()
```

since play-reactivemongo format considers BSONObjectID only when "$oid" is followed by string

```
implicit object BSONObjectIDFormat extends PartialFormat[BSONObjectID] {
  def partialReads: PartialFunction[JsValue, JsResult[BSONObjectID]] = {
    case JsObject(("$oid", JsString(v)) +: Nil) => JsSuccess(BSONObjectID(v))
  }
  val partialWrites: PartialFunction[BSONValue, JsValue] = {
    case oid: BSONObjectID => Json.obj("$oid" -> oid.stringify)
  }
}
```

Still, I hope there is a cleaner solution. If not, I guess it makes it a nice pull request.

Comment: where to register `BSONObjectIDFormat ` ?

Comment: @HarmeetSinghTaara you can have it wherever you want. What you need to do is bringing it into scope wherever you need to do this. Like `import package.BSONObjectIDFormat`

Comment: when i call `request.body.validate[User]` `validate` method, this will automatically? my request format as like `{ "_id":{"$oid":"54fd4b7084071e6a6ab13cee"} "name" : "Akka", "age" : 30, "created" : 1425886070013 }`

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if transforming id to BSONObjectID isn't more secure this way :

```
val ids: List[String] = ???
val bsonObjectIds = ids.map(BSONObjectID.parse(_)).collect{case Success(t) => t}
```

this will only generate valid BSONObjectIDs (and discard invalid ones)
If you do it this way :

```
val objectIds = ids.map(id => Json.obj("$oid" -> id))
```

your objectIds may not be valid ones depending on string id really being the stringify version of a BSONObjectID or not

Answer (score 0):

If you import `play.modules.reactivemongo.json._` it work without any $oid formatters.

```
import play.modules.reactivemongo.json._
...
val ids: Seq[BSONObjectID] = ???
val selector = Json.obj("_id" -> Json.obj("$in" -> ids))
usersCollection.find(selector).cursor[User].collect[Seq]()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the following and it worked for me:

```
val listOfItems = BSONArray(51, 61)

val query = BSONDocument("_id" -> BSONDocument("$in" -> listOfItems))

val ruleListFuture = bsonFutureColl.flatMap(_.find(query, Option.empty[BSONDocument]).cursor[ResponseAccDataBean]().
      collect[List](-1, Cursor.FailOnError[List[ResponseAccDataBean]]()))
```